# Scala - infix operator for super can't be called infix

Tags: java, scala

Suppose I have the following structure

```
trait A {
    def \ (v: String) = ...
    def + (v: String) = ...
}

case class B extends A {
    override def \ (v: String) = {
        // Do something here
        super \ v
    }
    override def + (v: String) = {
        // Do something here
        this + v
    }
}
```

At `super \ v` I get an error saying `'.' expected but identifier found`
This code works if I use the dot notation instead of the infix one like so: `super.\(v)`
So my question is:

**Why can't I use infix operators with `super` but I can use them with `this`?**

Is this some sort of a Java thing in scala or is there some thought process behind it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#this-and-super:

```
SimpleExpr  ::=  [id `.'] `this'
              |  [id '.'] `super' [ClassQualifier] `.' id
```

So `super` by itself isn't an expression, and at http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#infix-operations you can see the left-hand operand of an infix operation must be an expression (to be more precise, a `PrefixExpr`, which is defined as `['-' | '+' | '~' | '!'] SimpleExpr`).